# When down-shifting my rear derailleur (Campagnolo 10spd) is skipping multiple gears.

Tags: shifter, derailleur-rear, skipping

The problem feels like it is in the shifter as it just "lets go" when I press it. I'm told it could be the G spring. Is it something in the derailleur or the shifter? If its the shifter is replacing the G spring an easy task (doesn't look like it is in the exploded diagram!).

Comment: What happens if you merely tension the inner wire with your hand?  Does it change one cog at a time then?   How's the wear on the cassette, chain, and jockey wheels?  Has this got worse over time or has it suddenly started?

Comment: Could you tell us the exact model/versions of your levers/derailleurs. I know some Campag levers let you downshift multiple gears in one go, so it could be something like the 'click' per cog has become worn or something? Causing you to overshift.

Comment: Taking a shifter apart is almost always a bad idea, I still have a box in the garage with a disassembled  Shimano 105 shifter that just won't go back together! The problem however could just be a sticky cable - friction in the housing leads to you having to over tension the cable to change up and the spring pulls it down multiple shifts when you release. Changing the outer and cable is a cheap place to start and in my experience it solves 99% of gear related issues!

Comment: Campagnolo 10 speed systems are supposed to shift several gears at once. Does it downshift 2-4 gears and stops or continues to the lowest gear possible? If it is 1 it is only normal, if it is 2, the derailleur spring may be broken.

Comment: @ilikeprogramming G spring is the part that produces the 'click'.

Comment: With indexed shifters, other than the twist type, it's common for the lube in the shifter to become congealed, preventing the ratchet pawls from operating correctly.  You may especially notice this when it's cold.  The usual fix is to spray lube into the shifter (though the type of spray to use is kind of a superstition thing).

Comment: Four years later, user1667426, how did you know where to drill the hole for the set screw and spring?

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer to your query depends on the model and age of the system.

If it's an older system from the Record or Chorus ranges, when they were still 10s (pre 2009), then yes, the G-springs are a possibility.

If it's from pre 2007 and is from the lower Campagnolo ranges (Xenon, Mirage, Veloce or Centaur) then it could possibly be a G-spring issue - all of these ranges pre 2007 used a lever mechanism basically the same internally as a Record or Chorus 10s lever - Xenon moved away from that mechanism in 2004/5, Mirage etc in 2007 to a system called Escape.

The G-Spings (AKA the P springs - it depends what letter you think they resemble) are two springs which engage a ratchet. The ratchet is what sets the index interval and if one or both springs fail, or if the mount ring that holds them in place fails, you can get the problem that you describe although normally in these types of lever, if tou have a system that "falls through" all of the gears, the shift in the other direction won't "hold" a gear reliably either.

Levers of this type can be repaired as others have noted. If you don't want to tackle it yourself, we offer the service here at Velotech Cycling Ltd - please drop me an email at the address below, for more info.

Post 2007 and Pre 2009 Xenon through to Centaur all used "Escape". These levers have no G springs, but an escapement mechanism. If that is proving troublesome in the way you describe, the only relaible & long term fix is a complete lever body, Campagnolo part number EC-VL100.

Veloce and Centuar 2009 - 2011 used an UltraShift mechanism. These are serviceable but this kind of issue is very rare - I'd suggest a call in to a Campagnolo Pro-Shop (see the Campagnolo website for a listing) or drop us an email at Velotech - we are the main UK Service Centre - email us at velotechcycling"at"aim"dot"com.

Veloce and Centaur 2012-present - again, a system that works basically like Escape, called PowerShift - the only relaible fix is a new lever body complete, part number EC-CE300.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is about first and second generation Ergopower, the Escape mechanism is different and should never downshift several gears at time.

The G-spring is a small piece of wire shaped like capital G, located inside the shifter. When it is worn out, the clicks feel less crisp and it is easy to accidentally shift multiple gears at a time.

The spring is fairly easy to replace if you have any experience disassembling mechanical things. The Campagnolo mechanism is extremely simple compared to Shimano, but the price of simplicity is the spring that wears out.

EDIT: Not UltraShift. See the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the information. Being a newer model Centaur, the only solution was to replace the lever body, so it went from a $10 part with $70 labour (too hard for me to tackle) to $110 part with $20 labour. At lest its now done and riding smoothly again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Mirage 10 shifter. After taking it apart I figured out a way to repair it. I drilled a hole through the shifter body perpendicular to the ratchet. Then I put a strong spring in the hole and pushed it down with a set screw. I tightened the screw until there was just enough pressure to allow up shifting. Now on the down shift it indexes perfectly. [image: ergopower escape body hole][image: set screw and spring]

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]! Thanks for answering one of our questions. Is the hole that you drilled visible in the pic? If so, please edit the answer to either explain where the hole is, or edit the image to point out the hole. BTW, we recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site